# Container did not start during docker stack deploy, could not find or load main class, unable to diagnose further

Tags: java, docker, tomcat

I am helping on a project which consists of a Docker stack with a bunch of services all working together. All of them start except for one.

Using `docker service ps my-service --no-trunc` gives me: `task: non-zero exit(1)`

Using `docker service logs my-service` gives me: `Error: could not find or load main class`

This particular container has a Java application running in support of a NodeJS server. After `npm install`, `npm run init`, `npm run build`, and `mvn clean install`, I was able to successfully build the Docker image. No errors.

However, now it's not actually starting. I can't figure out how to diagnose it any further. The error message doesn't tell me a whole lot. The Java code is old, but it should work, I never touched it.

Mainly, I don't know where to progress from here. Google searches turn up only stuff where they have access to a lot more debugging information, and I just don't have enough to go on. Java is not my strength. What am I missing?

UPDATE 3/21/19: Thanks to @VinDev, I was able to get some more detailed information (it should've been obvious to me to try this, but it's good to learn).

Used `docker run --name TestMyContainer -it my-image bash` to start up the container, then ran the normal starting command for the container in the stack, which is `catalina.sh run`. That gave me the following output:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /docker-java-home/jre
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class
```

UPDATE #2 3/21/19: I was able to solve the issue. I should've included more information: I'm on a Windows machine, but making Linux containers. I found the answer here: [Tomcat startup - Error: Could not find or load main class](https://serverfault.com/questions/885854/tomcat-startup-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class)

Windows had reverted the `setenv.sh` file to CRLF EOL. I changed it back in Visual Studio Code, ran the container again, and everything works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this to the original post, but adding it here as well to properly mark the question as answered:

I was able to solve the issue. I should've included more information: I'm on a Windows machine, but making Linux containers. I found the answer here: [Tomcat startup - Error: Could not find or load main class](https://serverfault.com/questions/885854/tomcat-startup-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class)

Windows had reverted the `setenv.sh` file to CRLF EOL. I changed it back in Visual Studio Code, ran the container again, and everything works!

Answer (score 0):

Run `docker service ls` to see if the service shows up ...

also run `docker service inspect my-service`

This should give you a container id you can use to get the logs

```
docker logs CONTAINER_ID
```

You can also run the container by itself

```
docker run IMAGE_NAME
```

to see the result of just running it as a container

```
/usr/local/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
```

Seems it can't find `bootstrap.jar` or `tomcat-juli.jar`

Maybe not being copied by Dockerfile?

Comment: The service is in the list, yes, but shows `replicas` as `0/1`.

Unfortunately, I already had the container logs, the less than helpful `Error: could not find or load main class`

Comment: (accidentally submitted while I was still working)

Created the new test container with just the bash command, then manually put in the starting command used in the actual stack, `catalina.sh run`, and got some more detailed information, which I have placed above.

Thanks!

Comment: Saw your edit. I actually found the answer at https://serverfault.com/questions/885854/tomcat-startup-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class, and the problem occurred because I'm on a Windows machine which keeps changing my EOL from LF to CRLF.

Comment: awesome glad you found the answer! EOL 